# How does Stirling engine work exactly?

Tags: thermodynamics

How does [Stirling engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_engine) work exactly? What I am really curious about is how one side is hot and the other cold at the same time all the time shouldn't the heat source heat one side then the heat move to the other side and they become both hot
and another thing I don't understand is after one side is heated the piston move outward after that how does the fluid move to the other side or why does it entirely leave the hot side
please explain to me as much as possible about this engine

Comment: The [wikipedia site on Stirling engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_engine) is pretty complete, and it has some nice animations (scroll down) that indicate how it works.

Comment: @march the reason why I do not recommend this wkipedia article is this crucially wrong sentence there "*The maximum theoretical efficiency is equivalent to that of the Carnot cycle, but the efficiency of real engines is less than this value because of friction and other losses*." In fact, the Stirling cycle efficiency is less than the Carnot efficiency; this is bacic thermodynamics.

Comment: @hyportnext.  Okay: but the animations are nice, and the description of how it works is good too.

Comment: @march I agree with you on that. Anyhow, I am just as astonished at how many *other* places, too, this false claim about the Stirling engine is made.

Comment: @hyportnex That might just be because people ignore the actual statement about the efficiency of a reversible engine: that is, "The efficiency of a reversible engine *that operates between two temperatures* is the Carnot efficiency," but the reversible version of a Stirling engine can't operate between only two temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

A common yet simple Stirling engine structure can be seen at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtF3-YmHp_0.  It is two circular metal plates connected by a heat-insulating plastic rim.  The piston can is a small flexible material, perhaps rubber.  The small area increases the vertical motion as gas volume changes.  A foam pad is connected to the crankshaft to keep its motion one-fourth of a cycle out of phase with the piston.  External contact with the hot and cool environments keep the hot plate and cold plate fairly steady.  When the foam pad is up, the air is warmed by the bottom plate.  When the pad is down, the air is cooled by the top plate.